# Dynamic auto-completion options when using a JSON schema in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've been experimenting with VSCode's options for auto-completion and linting of JSON/YAML files I'm authoring with a JSON schema I've defined. The basics using `json.schemas` in `settings.json` was straightforward. What I'm now looking into is to how I can dynamically load auto-complete values for users based on what they have access to.

Here's a crude example:

```json
{
    "operations": [
        {
            "id": "<Show-a-list-of-all-valid-IDs-here-to-select>"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above example I'm adding an operation to an array (as defined by my schema), but the operations I have access to are behind an API and each one has some differing schema properties. My goal would be to expose all the valid options as auto-completes, and then insert the full object with all of the required fields.

This isn't too different from [snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_define-snippets-in-json-schemas). Is this a scenario where I would be better served abusing VSCode's schema support, or should I look into building an extension? If I should go the extension route, where do I begin for one that's built around schema auto-completion?

Comment: probably extension. actually... I'm curious whether it would work to define your schema file dynamically?

Comment: @starball That's what I'm wondering too. I could generate all of the possible options as snippets if the URI is an endpoint that generates it on the fly.